# apply plugin: 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.4' gives me an error

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, github

im trying to upload my code to github without also uploading my unenctypted api key. This plugin is supposed to make it so that the api is pulled from the local.propertied(which is part of git ignore) instead. However I when i try to sync I get the error "apply plugin: 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' not found

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing, but without success yet. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @viana nothing ever worked.